# How to query dynamodb table with only one attribute as a filter condition?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I need to fetch a list of records from dynamo table by filtering the records of last 24 hours and product name(one of the attributes).

I searched the documentation but it is so vast and complex and time taking to understand. I am expecting a solution to this either to find an DynamoDB API or function that takes in attributes as filters and returns the records that match the condition, just like as a where condition in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PartiQL API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html), which gives your SQL like syntax.

`SELECT * FROM "mytable" WHERE foo = 'bar'`